# Why markdown lines pasted from vim to github gets linearized

Tags: github, markdown

I just started with the github and markdown, created my first README.md.
Edited text in vim and wanted see how it would be previewed in the github. However my line breaks were "deleted" (several lines became one long line).

How can I fix this problem?

This is what I did:

1. Edited text in vim

   > > My email(space)(space)
   >   > My name(space)(space)
2. Pasted text into the github code editor and checked the preview
3. My text became

   > > My email(space)> My name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure those two spaces are preserved when you copy uour text from vim to the GitHub editor.

If those spaces are there, then your newline will be preserved in the preview.